# VB wait webpage load

Tags: .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control, html, wait

I need help about VB wait webpage load.
With one button click => navigate one page and wait to load, then change one label text, then navigate another page and wait to load, then change another label text, then navigate and wait to load another page, then change label text. Please help me, i try with this code, but fail...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click ...
WebBrowser1.Navigate("page1")
Label1.Text = "Loaded" 'but this show before the page loaded
WebBrowser1.Navigate("page2") 'this start loading before the page1 loaded
Label2.Text = "Loaded" 'but this show before the page loaded
WebBrowser1.Navigate("page3") 'this start loading before the page1 loaded
Label3.Text = "Loaded"
...
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a `DocumentCompleted` event for the webbrowser where you can use.

Comment: yes, but how to use it for 3-4-5 pages. can you give me a code? :))

Comment: inside the event, check for the webbrowser's url and based on that, set the appropriate label to "Loaded".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of which page is loading. You can do this with a `Static` variable.

When the first one completes (the documentcompleted event fires) then load the next one:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click
    'Load the first page
    LoadNextPage
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    'When the current page has finished loading - load the next page
    LoadNextPage
End Sub

Private Sub LoadNextPage
    Static page As Integer = 0 'set to page number we are loading
    'increment the page count
    page += 1
    'Load the appropriate page
    Select Case page
        Case 1
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("page1")
        Case 2
            Label1.Text = "Loaded 1 now loading 2" 
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("page2") 
        Case 3
            Label2.Text = "Loaded 2 now loading 3" 
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("page3") 
        Case Else
            Label3.Text = "Loaded All Documents"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It's start when i run the program, before the button click. How can i fix this?

Comment: You must have some code in the Form_Load event then? - Fix it by removing that code.

Comment: please give me your email or skype, i wanna to ask you something

Comment: Please ask any question on here so that everyone can benefit

Comment: I have problem, on case 2 load "case else" and skip case 3? How can i fix this?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Please upvote my answer if it has helped you and mark as accepted if it gave the answer to your original question

Comment: Just say me why the program skip case 3 and go directly to case else? :)

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your code which is why I suggested posting a new question. If you used the code I posted then `Case 3` would not be skipped so there must be some difference.